# ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: 274668

Tags: oracle, shell

all

I am trying to call a shell script from PL/SQL. I created a program and a job and enabled them.

```
 exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name=>'oam.loadLog_job',job_type=>'EXECUTABLE',job_action=>'/gx_working/select2.sh');
```

When I tried run the code above I got the following error;

```
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: 274668
```

I searched the internet, the exit_code 274668 is "invalid run_group specified in externaljob.ora file"

So, What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Thanks.

my externaljob.ora file is like that:

```
# $Header: externaljob.ora 16-dec-2005.20:47:13 rramkiss Exp $
#
# Copyright (c) 2005, Oracle. All rights reserved.
# NAME
#   externaljob.ora
# FUNCTION
#   This configuration file is used by dbms_scheduler when executing external
#   (operating system) jobs. It contains the user and group to run external
#   jobs as. It must only be writable by the owner and must be owned by root.
#   If extjob is not setuid then the only allowable run_user
#   is the user Oracle runs as and the only allowable run_group is the group
#   Oracle runs as.
#
# NOTES
#   For Porters: The user and group specified here should be a lowly privileged
#                user and group for your platform. For Linux this is nobody
#                and nobody.
# MODIFIED
#     rramkiss   12/09/05 -  Creation
#
##############################################################################
# External job execution configuration file externaljob.ora
#
# This file is provided by Oracle Corporation to help you customize
# your RDBMS installation for your site.  Important system parameters
# are discussed, and default settings given.
#
# This configuration file is used by dbms_scheduler when executing external
# (operating system) jobs. It contains the user and group to run external
# jobs as. It must only be writable by the owner and must be owned by root.
# If extjob is not setuid then the only allowable run_user
# is the user Oracle runs as and the only allowable run_group is the group
# Oracle runs as.

run_user = nobody
run_group = nobody
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Make sure that there is space on both side of the equal sign. And there is an bug as well-Bug 11814763 which has been fixed in Oracle 12.1 version.

Comment: yes,i am sure that there is space on both side of the equal sign.and the oracle version is 11g.